# Trying to split table into two columns

Tags: html, html-table, fieldset

I am trying to get a table to split in half and one part be on the left and the other section to be on the right but the table keeps staying on one side. I want the input fields to line up the inline the column names that is why I am trying to put it in a table.

Below screenshot indicates what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

```html
<fieldset class="Application">
  <Legend>
    <h2>Owners, Officers, Partners Information</h2>
  </legend>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="ownname" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="title" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Percentage Held:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="percent" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Street:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="ownstreet" size="10">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>City-State-Zip:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="owncity" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SSN:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="SSN" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="ownname" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="title" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Percentage Held:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="percent" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Street:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="ownstreet" size="10">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>City-State-Zip:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="owncity" size="10" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SSN:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="SSN" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>

  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While creating a snippet, please click on "Tidy" button after adding the code. It formats the code properly and improves readability. I have also added your image into the question. When using tags, just hover on the tag names and if you see "Do not use this tag" for any tag, avoid tagging it (like **table** tag in this case). The tag **tr** is also not suitable for this question because it is used for a *nix utility. I think you are unaware of these as you are new.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="Application">
  <table>
    <legend>
      <h2>Owners, Officers, Partners Information</h2>
    </legend>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="ownname" size="10" />
          </td>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="ownname" size="10" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Title:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="title" size="10" />
          </td>
          <td>Title:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="title" size="10" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Percentage Held:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="percent" size="10" />
          </td>
          <td>Percentage Held:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="percent" size="10" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Street:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="ownstreet" size="10">
          </td>
          <td>Street:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="ownstreet" size="10">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City-State-Zip:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="owncity" size="10" />
          </td>
          <td>City-State-Zip:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="owncity" size="10" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SSN:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="SSN" />
          </td>
          <td>SSN:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="SSN" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped a lot with what im trying to do